# different streams for different stream types - struts2

Tags: struts2

in my application , user have option to download in xls only . now we are modifying it using apache poi. the earlier struts tag was

```
<class="com.msl.mo.exporttoexcel.ExportToExcel">
    <result name="success" type="stream">
        <param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
        <paramname="contentType">application/vnd.mexcel</param>

        <param name="contentDisposition">filename="WOlist.xlsx"</param>
        <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
    </result>
```

i want that if user chooses xls in dialog a different stream is used and for xlsx a different stream is used.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have different way to achieve this.

Create a different result type and configure them in your struts xml file like

```
 <result name="xls" type="stream">
             <param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
            <paramname="contentType">application/vnd.xls</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">filename="WOlist.xls"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
 </result>

 <result name="xlsx" type="stream">
             <param name="inputName">fileStream</param>
            <paramname="contentType">application/vnd.mexcel</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">filename="WOlist.xlsx"</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
 </result>
```

and you can configure them for more result type based on the result string being returned from the action class
else you can set the values of stream and other parameters in your action class and can use dynamic value sin your result configuration like

```
<result name="success" type="stream">
             <param name="inputName">${fileStream}</param>
            <paramname="contentType">${contentType}</param>
            <param name="contentDisposition">${filename}</param>
            <param name="bufferSize">${bufferSize}</param>
 </result>
```

where all these parameters `fileStream,contentType,filename,bufferSize` can be set inside your Action class based on the value entered by the user,this will give you more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks umesh  but once action dispatches result to browser , then only user can select the filetype based on which i can decide which stream i want to send, is there a way to do it.

Comment: @user930412 even if user select a file type i assume that you need some sort of handing at action side or you want it all in client side? which in my opinion is not good way to go

Comment: yes but file selection option comes only after action has dispatched result to browser, now after that there is no programming power with action. isnt it?

Comment: that means you have something wrong in design since what if you have to add one more type in your action? that means you need to create all type in your action and make them ready for user where user will at the end choose any one.I am afraid in that case Struts2 can not help you and you have to do some client side scripting for that

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted to hear that struts can't help me

Comment: When its comes to client side this is your own implementations Struts2 can only provide assistance and in your case you have already passed control from Struts2 action so Struts2 is out of picture as of now :)